# How many questions/answers do ALL the other Stack Exchange sites have?

Tags: discussion, statistics

[Seeing site stats](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#answers) I realized that there's no site that exceeds 1 million neither in amount of questions nor answers, while Stack Overflow, the main site, has way above 10M in both.

If we add all the questions/answers from **every** other site, including public beta, do they exceed the 12M/19M amount of Stack Overflow?

Comment: Well, you can simply add up the numbers on that page and find out :-)

Comment: Yes this is a bit "Here are the numbers, can someone else add them all up for me" question.

Comment: I was not asking for adding up *only for me*, but I thought *someone* has already done it before, *regardless of my question*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The number of questions on all sites *except Stack Overflow*, but *including all meta Sites* is ~3.86 million (as of last Sunday). You can find this number by running [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/508433) (thanks @rene for vastly improving mine):

```sql
-- all databases
declare  db_c cursor for select [name] 
                         from sys.databases 
                         where database_id > 5 -- skip master, temp, model, msdb, Data.SE

declare @db_c_name sysname   -- holds name of db after fetch
declare @sql nvarchar(max) -- holds build up sql string

-- result table
create table #questions ( site nvarchar(250), numberOfQuestions int, numberOfAnswers int);

open db_c
fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    set @sql = N'use '+ QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) + ';
    insert into #questions 
    select ''' + QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) + '''
    , sum(case when posttypeid = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
    , sum(case when posttypeid = 2 then 1 else 0 end)
      from posts
      where posttypeid in (1,2)';
    exec (@sql)
   fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
end;
close db_c;
deallocate db_c;

select 'The rest' as [sites]
      , sum(numberOfQuestions) as [# Q]
      , sum(numberOfAnswers) as [# A]
from #questions where site != '[StackOverflow]'
union
select 'Stack Overflow',  numberOfQuestions, numberofAnswers from #questions where site = '[StackOverflow]'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Interesting to see, how heavily dominant Stack Overflow is, even after years of the existence of this network.

Answer (score 11):

You can do some jQuery on the page to find out from the values that exist on the page itself:

```
$('.lv-stats-wrapper').find('.lv-stats-box:first > span > span')
.map(function(){ return parseInt(this.title.split(' ')[0].replace(/,/g, ''), 10); })
.slice(1).toArray()
.reduce(function(prev, curr){ return prev + curr; }, 0);
```

(this assumes Stack Overflow is first in the list and that the list view is shown).

First line - selects the spans with the number of questions (for answers, instead of `:first` use `:nth-child(2)`).

Second line - parses the `title` attribute to the full value as integer.

Third line - removes the first item (usually Stack Overflow) and returns a plain integer array.

Last line - sums them up.

---

Just past the above into your console on the [sites page](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#answers) and off you go :)

Comment: +1 for using jQuery. How stupid of me, trying to use an inferior technology...

Comment: +1 [jQuery best](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492)!